Connections to SQL Server databases files require LocalDB or SQL Server express
so I'm basically having this issue in Visual Studio when I try to add a "Service-based Database".

Connections to SQL Server database files (.mdf) require LocalDB or SQL Server Express to be installed and running on the local computer. You may need to modify the setup and ensure Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools is selected and install the current version at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=125883

I have installed both, SQL Server Express and SQL Server developer, however the message still shows and i can't create the database.
Is there a way to solve this?

You could instead simply use Microsoft SQL Management Studio. It is meant to manage anything related to Microsoft SQL Server (any editions)

I used it, but my Visual Studio doesn't recognize it

Make sure your visual studio run with enough privilege to access the SQL server. Try running VS in admin and see. If your running admin you will see a box right beneath the maximize and close button on the top right of VS with "ADMIN" written on it.
